# UILabel in a UICollectionViewCell not showing on newly dequeued cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and a custom cell subclassing UICollectionViewCell which contains a UILabel. In cellForItemAtIndexPath I'm dequeuing, setting the UILabel's text and returning the cell as normal.

When it loads, everything looks correct, but when when I scroll newly dequeued cell's label text is blank even though I've logged out the string that's being set and it's correct.

I'm not adding or removing anything from the cell and nothing's set to hidden.

As a test, I set the background color of the label and the background position and size looks correct so I don't think the label's misplaced.

Any ideas?

I'm not sure if it's relevant but I'm using Xcode 8.1, Swift 2.3 and seeing similar behaviour on both an actual iPad and iPhone as well as the simulator.

The code that @zac-kwan asked for:

```
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Location Cell Vertical Left", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? LocationCollectionViewCellVertical else {
    print("Couldn't get locationCollectionViewCellVertical")
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

The inside of the guard statement is never called.

...

```
cell.locationTitleLabel.text = originalString
```

`originalString` always contains a valid string.

**Update:**

The strangest part is that if I scroll so those problematic cells are off the screen and then scroll so they're visible again, they appear correctly.

Comment: From your description and the test you did, everything seems good here. Maybe can you post the code where you dequeue and set the label so we can help to debug?

Comment: Sadly I can't post much of the code here, but it's a standard `collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Location Cell Vertical Left", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? LocationCollectionViewCellVertical` and `cell.locationTitleLabel.text = originalString`

Comment: You can actually edit your question to have the code there

Comment: Your string may contain "\n" so it is not visible unless it has enough to show. Test with constant data

Comment: Thanks @adnbsr but I just tried your suggestion and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

use break point and in console po yourLabelName and check frame

Comment: Logging the frame, I'm getting a smaller width than I'd expect — smaller than all the other cells. As I mentioned, I can see the background colour in the place where I'd expect to see the label so it's in the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

[collectioView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"collectionViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"].To register the nib file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think I need to do this as the cell is a prototype in the collectionview in the storyboard. Is that correct?